# How to make Python open up Chrome webdrivers faster?

Tags: python, chrome-web-driver

Using this code:

```
from datetime import datetime, time
from time import sleep
import numpy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from multiprocessing import Process

def dateDiffInSeconds(date1, date2):
  timedelta = date2 - date1
  return timedelta.days * 24 * 3600 + timedelta.seconds

def daysHoursMinutesSecondsFromSeconds(seconds):
    minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    days, hours = divmod(hours, 24)
    return (days, hours, minutes, seconds)

req = datetime.strptime('2020-03-23 20:31:50', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
now = datetime.now()

while req < now:
  driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\royce\\Desktop\\bot\\chromedriver.exe")
  driver.get ('https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/sweatshirts')
  driver.maximize_window()
  driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Rammellzee').click()
  break
```

And doing it through running the program in IDLE Python. When I run the program it takes around 5 seconds to even up Chrome because it goes through Python shell and then the actual Python (the one that looks like cmd) and then when it does open up Chrome its a blank screen for around another 5 seconds. The tutorial I was following of someone using the same webdriver code opens up their Chrome instantly. However, they did it through Sublime Text so I tried that as well but the same code set to Python on Sublime Text doesn't even do anything.

Comment: Does Chrome take more time to open when launched from your program than when you launch it manually/yourself? _The tutorial I was following of someone using the same webdriver code opens up their chrome instantly._ Are your computers very similar in performance otherwise? If the answer to both those questions is no, then I'm not sure how much can be done.

Comment: normally chrome opens instantly for me and i have a very good pc but I think it may have something to do with the fact the person was doing it through sublime text but I don't know how to get the program to even work at all on there with the same exact code.

Comment: The choice of IDE/text editor shouldn't make a difference. _I don't know how to get the program to even work at all on there with the same exact code._ You likely don't need to do much, there should be no need to change the code. It might make more sense to benchmark a program which does nothing but open Chrome, and compare it's performance to opening Chrome normally. I'm still convinced there won't be much of a difference, though.

Comment: I tried only opening up chrome on its own through the driver and it is still awfully slow. I believe it must be something with the driver even though I tried reinstalling. Do you know any other drivers that I could use don't have to necessarily be chrome? Or maybe another way to tackle the problem because I can open chrome in a different way but I don't know how to do text recognition of what is on my screen. Do you know any ways i can do that?

Comment: _Do you know any other drivers that I could use don't have to necessarily be chrome?_ I use Firefox, I don't find it particularly slow. _Or maybe another way to tackle the problem because I can open chrome in a different way but I don't know how to do text recognition of what is on my screen. Do you know any ways i can do that?_ Ah, that's another topic entirely. As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.